# TSQL Sum Rows with dates less than date value for each distinct date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table structured like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vt](
[id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ones] [money] NULL,
[twos] [money] NULL,
[fives] [money] NULL,
[tens] [money] NULL,
[twenties] [money] NULL,
[fifties] [money] NULL,
[hundreds] [money] NULL,
[ReportDate] [datetime] NULL)
```

How can I write a query to do what the query below does for each distinct ReportDate:

```
declare @date datetime
set @date = '11/3/2014';
SELECT 
ISNULL(SUM([ones]), 0) AS ones
,ISNULL(SUM([twos]), 0) AS twos
,ISNULL(SUM([fives]), 0) AS fives
,ISNULL(SUM([tens]), 0) AS tens
,ISNULL(SUM([twenties]), 0) AS twenties
,ISNULL(SUM([fifties]), 0) AS fifties
,ISNULL(SUM([hundreds]), 0) AS hundreds
,max(ReportDate) as ReportDate
FROM [vt]
WHERE 
ReportDate is not null and reportDate <= (@date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
;WITH Dates AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ReportDate
    FROM [vt]
)
SELECT *
FROM Dates A
OUTER APPLY (   SELECT  ISNULL(SUM([ones]), 0) AS ones,
                        ISNULL(SUM([twos]), 0) AS twos,
                        ISNULL(SUM([fives]), 0) AS fives,
                        ISNULL(SUM([tens]), 0) AS tens,
                        ISNULL(SUM([twenties]), 0) AS twenties,
                        ISNULL(SUM([fifties]), 0) AS fifties,
                        ISNULL(SUM([hundreds]), 0) AS hundreds,
                        MAX(ReportDate) as ReportDate
                FROM [vt]
                WHERE reportDate <= A.ReportDate) B
```

Answer (score 3):

You can inner join the table to itself on the report date <= report date.

```
SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(b.[ones]), 0) AS ones ,
        ISNULL(SUM(b.[twos]), 0) AS twos ,
        ISNULL(SUM(b.[fives]), 0) AS fives ,
        ISNULL(SUM(b.[tens]), 0) AS tens ,
        ISNULL(SUM(b.[twenties]), 0) AS twenties ,
        ISNULL(SUM(b.[fifties]), 0) AS fifties ,
        ISNULL(SUM(b.[hundreds]), 0) AS hundreds ,
        a.ReportDate
FROM    [vt] a
INNER JOIN [vt] b ON b.ReportDate <= a.ReportDate
WHERE   a.ReportDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.ReportDate
```

Comment: Wow, that was the fastest -1 I've ever received, 1.5 seconds after posting the answer.

Comment: Not my downvote, but your answer is wrong. Op wants to have the cumulative sum for every date, your answer doesn't do that

Comment: I see that now that you've posted an answer.  Let's see if I can come up with another way.

Comment: I believe this is better.

Comment: I think so. You are missing a `GROUP BY` though

Comment: Upvoted because it seems to be simpler than my answer.

Comment: I upvoted yours because your got it first AND got it right the first time.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: ...
WHERE a.ReportDate IS NOT NULL ...
Since it is an INNER JOIN.
This condition will always be true right?